# CSV - Grep a particular pattern, print first match and the first line of that file

Tags: regex, csv, sed, grep

I have multiple CSV files

```
> File 1
name,age,city
john,30,NY
cassey,25,SF
nick,25,DC

> File 2
attended,days
math,30
phy,25
che,25

> File 3
days, weeks
30, 4
20, 5
```

I want to search for a entry and when I get it, I want to stop at the first entry. However, I also want to print the first line of the file, as it is a CSV, it will help me with the name of the columns

If I search for 25, my desired output is

```
File 1:
  name,age,city
  cassey,25,SF
File 2:
  attended,days
  phy,25
```

With the following code, I'm able to print

```
# grep -m 1 25 * -rn
cassey,25,SF
phy,25
```

How to pipe the grep output to sed or another utility so that I can print the first column and the matching column in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `sed` instead of grep. Use `ls` and `xargs` to proces many files:

```
ls file* | xargs -n1 sed -n '1{x;d}; /25/{x;p;x;p;q}'
```

The reason for all 'x;p' is to not print the first line if pattern is not found in the file.

file1:

```
name,age,city
cassey,25,SF
```

file2:

```
attended,days
phy,25
at,25
```

file3:

```
attended,days
phy,26
```

Result:

```
$ ls file* | xargs -n1 sed -n '1{x;d}; /25/{x;p;x;p;q}'
name,age,city
cassey,25,SF
attended,days
phy,25
```

Edit: Printing the file name - now a proper bash loop:

```
$ for i in `grep -l 25 file*` ; do echo $i; head -n1 $i; grep -m1 25 $i; done
file1
  name,age,city
  cassey,25,SF
file2
  attended,days
  phy,25
```

Comment: Now that is somewhat harder. In that case I'd use grep first to find whether the pattern is in the file at all, then print file name, first line and matching line. All that as a normal bash script with a loop. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && /25/ {print; exit}' file
name,age,city
cassey,25,SF
```

That is, when the `NR` (number of record, here number of line) is 1, print it. From that moment on, whenever a line matches the pattern, print it and exit.

---

To check in all files:

```
for file in *
do
   echo "$file"
   awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && /25/ {print; exit}' $file
done
```

Where `*` can be a file pattern like `file*`. In that case, it will loop through all the files whose name starts with `file`.

---

To just print those file names which match, do:

```
for file in *
do
   do grep -q 25 "$file" && echo "$file" && awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && /25/ {print; exit}' $file
done
```

`grep -q` returns true if there is a match. In that case, it proceeds and prints the file name and the line.

Comment: Thanks.. Your solution works for my initial question. I was not very clear with my question, so I now edited my original question.. I have mulitple files, and I want the search to continue.. And I want the file names also to be printed..

Comment: What about wrapping in a bash loop? `for file in *; do echo $file; awk ...; done`?

Comment: This prints all the file names and the first line of all files. I only want to print the file names and the first line of the matching files

Comment: Why don't you try to give all the requirements all together? It is tiring to keep updating based on new requirements.

Comment: This also works. Instead of going with the for loop with each file, if we can loop through `grep -l 25 *`, then it will be bit faster..

Comment: Mmmm yes, but at the same time you are grepping these files twice.